# transfer function with dead time

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, transfer-function

I have the following transfer function:

> (5/(s^2+1) ) * e^(-0.1*s)

How do I include the dead time in the transfer function model?

I tried `A=tf([5],[1 0 1],'td',0.1)` but doesn't work (`td` undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
A=tf([5],[1 0 1],'inputdelay',0.1)
```

The output from Matlab is:

```
Transfer function:
                 5
exp(-0.1*s) * -------
              s^2 + 1
```

The reason you received the error `td not defined` is because 'td' is not a recognized input value from the function. If you desire you use td, you can do this:

```
td = 'inputdelay'
A=tf([5],[1 0 1],td,0.1)
```

and the output will be the same.